# Questions about an article "how to create a flow in PA to change a value of column "Modify by" in a SP List

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow, power-automate, variable

I have an article that shows how to modify a value in the column "Modify By" of a SharePoint List with Power Automate. I have a question regarding about the flow:

http://johnliu.net/blog/2019/2/flowninja-hack-78-modifying-modified-by-and-modified-time-with-microsoft-flow

How can I add the variable?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

1. Inside compose action, Click where you want add the variable/output of previous action.
2. Click on **Add dynamic content**
3. Select the desired variable/output of previous action from the popup opened at the right side

[image]

---

**Updated from comments**:

You need to use **Expression** to add **string()** function around output. Follow below steps:

1. Inside compose action, Click where you want add the variable/output of previous action.
2. Click on **Add dynamic content**
3. Select **Expression** from the popup opened at the right side
4. Type `string()` & put cursor inside parentheses
5. Click on **Dynamic content** from popup
6. Select the variable/output of previous action
7. Click **OK**

[image]

Comment: I can select the output of Compose User but in the article there is a string specified.

Comment: Check updated answer.

Comment: Thank you for the help